How can I rasterize a vector object, while keeping it's height value?
It's a simple building, with a height of 60 meters.
I tried using the vector-raster tool, but I ended up with a 40 GB object(?), that won't show up on the map. And then I used TIN interpolation (Clough-Toucher method), and I got a white rectangle-ish object.
Edit:
Here are the parameters I'm using on the vector-raster tool:


What parameters are you using on the vector-raster tool? Are you selecting the correct burn in parameter? It's difficult to help if we don't have the details. If you could edit your question to include a screenshot it would be useful.

Added a screenshot, sorry for the confusion!

I am unable to reproduce your issue, even with the same coordinate system. Here are my steps:
Use the rasterise tool
Do not enter a fixed value to burn.

You should have a result similar to the below, where the height attribute is burnt into the raster colour:


"It's best to use a degree based coordinate system when doing this, like WGS 84"
No, it isn't.

Sorry, removed.
